# Ember binding works in template but not through extend

Tags: ember.js

I can get bindings to work in the template [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fhyFJ/):

```
{{view App.MyView fooBinding:author}}
```

But when I do the same with `extend` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vr2E5/4/):

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend
    fooBinding: "App.ApplicationController.author"
```

it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why can't you use the first method? You can't refer to the `ApplicationController` like that since that is the class definition, not the instance.

Comment: I'm just tinkering with Ember to understand how it works. Just curious: What would the path be for the ApplicationController instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind in a `View` class, you should use a `Controller`.

As per naming conventions a view named `AuthorView` would be look for a `AuthorController` or auto-generate a basic controller. In your code, you are setting a binding to the class (which represents the type) instead of the instance (which is your concrete object).

If you create a controller, you can do define a `author` property there, and in your view class, you can define a binding such as `fooBinding: "controller.author"` since it knows that `controller` is an instance of `AuthorController`.

```
App.AuthorController = Ember.Controller.extend
    author: Author.create
        firstName: 'Bill'
        lastName: 'Buckley'

App.AuthorView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName: 'author'
    fooBinding: "controller.author"
    fullName: (->
            author = @get 'foo'
            "#{author.get('firstName')} #{author.get('lastName')}"
    ).property 'firstName', 'lastName'
```

This approach will force you to use `view.binding.property` in your handlebars templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='author'>
    Written by {{view.fullName}}
    <br />
    From Controller binding "fooBinding": {{view.foo.firstName}} {{view.foo.lastName}}
</script>
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/pHWCp/))

Another way to do this, is to set the `author` property from a Route via `Route#setupController`:

```
Author = Ember.Object.extend
    firstName: null
    lastName: null    
    fullName: (->
        author = @get 'foo'
        "#{@.get('firstName')} #{@.get('lastName')}"
    ).property 'firstName', 'lastName'

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend 
    setupController: (controller, model) ->
        controller.set 'author', Author.create
            firstName: 'Bill',
            lastName: 'Buckley'
```

And your templates can access the `author` property directly, since it's in that view's controller:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='author'>
    written by: {{author.fullName}}
</script>
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/npHwf/))

This way you don't have to set any binding anywhere.

Notes:
Create the computed properties in your object, as it might be used not only by the view, but from other objects which could be using the author instance and avoid initializing properties with `undefined`.

---

To better use Ember's capabilities, you can define a route for Author and set the controller's `content` property with your `Author` instance and add an `{{outlet}}` to your template. The framework will find your controller and connect the template, again, using naming conventions:

Handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='author'>
    written by: {{fullName}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Coffee

```
window.App = App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map ->
    @.route 'author', { path: '/'}

App.Author = Ember.Object.extend
    firstName: null
    lastName: null    
    fullName: (->
        "#{@.get('firstName')} #{@.get('lastName')}"
    ).property 'firstName', 'lastName'

App.AuthorRoute = Ember.Route.extend 
    setupController: (controller, model) ->
            # this could come from an api
            controller.set 'content', App.Author.create
                firstName: 'Bill',
                lastName: 'Buckley'

App.AuthorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/h7rnm/))

Comment: Changing the binding to "controller.author" makes my original example work. Without an AuthorController, the AuthorView's controller is the ApplicationController instance. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vr2E5/5/)

Comment: Yeah. That happens because the application controller holds the `author` object, but if you move to a different route, that might not work with the same path (`controller.author`). I know your sample doesn't use route, but once your app starts to grow, you'll most likely use it, that's why I made the sample using a route for author.